# react-material-ui withStyle props is empty

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to control the background color of the switch to props. However, the props of withStyles are empty.

```
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
import {withStyles, Theme, createStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import React from 'react';
import {PropsType} from "./propsType";

const AntSwitch = withStyles(({palette, props, ...other})=>{
    console.log('withStyles', props) // here is empty
    return ({
        switchBase: {
            '&$checked': {
                '& + $track': {
                    opacity: 1,
                    backgroundColor: (props as PropsType.Switch).activeColor ?? palette.primary.main,
                    borderColor: palette.primary.main,
                },
            },
        }
    })
})(Switch);

export default function TPSwitch(props: PropsType.Switch) {
    const {label, ...other} = props;
    console.log('other', props)
    return (
        <AntSwitch {...other} />
    )
};
```

pirnt in console

```
other {label: "on", activeColor: "#E74060"}
TPSwitch.tsx:8 withStyles {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`withStyles` does not take `props` as one of [its arguments](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component)

This is how you can access `props`. I simplified your example for clarity.

```js
const AntSwitch = withStyles(({ palette }) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: (props) => console.log(palette, props) || "hotpink"
  }
}))(Switch);
```

Comment: thank you so much your advice! the code work for me. but not perfectly. the props lambda is work in element attribute but not working on event. example, `'&$checked' : (props) =>({ color : props.customColor})` thanks.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand the problem. Does [reference a local rule](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet) help?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-jss-dynamic-global-value-j552b here is same issue. This issue is not simply about misrepresentation of names. I think this is a problem that many people experience. Thank you for your time. I'll find out more, so if you have any ideas, please let me know. thanks