# react-jss dynamic value not working in query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jss

i'm tried to control styles value with props using by react-jss

> https://cssinjs.org/react-jss/?v=v10.6.0

however, the dynamic value is not working in query!

this code is control global background-color with react-jss. this code is working perfectly. however, change background-color to using dynamic value in props. don't change value the background color.

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: ({ color }) => color 
  },
  "@global": { // with query
    body: {
      backgroundColor: 'yellow' //working!!
    }
  }
};
```

this code is not working.  I checked the `({ color }) => color` lambda function is called and value is correctly.

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: ({ color }) => color 
  },
  "@global": { // with query
    body: {
      backgroundColor: ({ color }) => color // not working
    }
  }
};
```

This is the full code with error.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createUseStyles } from "react-jss";

const styles = {
  root: { // with classKey
    backgroundColor: ({ color }) => color // working
  },
  "@global": { // with query
    body: {
      backgroundColor: ({ globalColor }) => globalColor // not work
    }
  }
};

const useStyles = createUseStyles(styles);

const App = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props);

  return <h1 className={classes.root}> Background should be yellow</h1>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App color="yellow" globalColor='red'/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

and here is codesandbox, this is not my account and code

> https://codesandbox.io/s/react-jss-dynamic-global-value-j552b

Comment: I think you have to get assess to the sheet object in order to update it after your component mounts. Refer to the following [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jss-dynamic-global-value-7n9rb?file=/src/index.js) for an example of how this was solved

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I use the material-uil library, which seems to use the jss sheet internally. So there is no way to get the sheet and update it as far as I know. This question is taken from here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67731785/react-material-ui-withstyle-props-is-empty.

Answer (score 0):

If using the material-ui library, use the [`makeStyles`](https://v3.material-ui.com/css-in-js/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook) function to create the `useStyles` hook.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

const styles = {
  "@global": {
    body: {
      backgroundColor: ({ color }) => color
    }
  }
};

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

let App = props => {
  useStyles(props);
  return <h1>Background should be yellow</h1>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App color="yellow" />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. i think the dynamic value has error in query, however I saw this and realized what I thought was wrong. There were more complicated conditions. I've arranged a more detailed situation here. [https://codesandbox.io/s/react-jss-dynamic-global-value-forked-069zt?file=/src/ErrorTest.jsx]  Whether this problem is solved or not, I appreciate your effort and time. Thanks to you, I could know more. Thanks